# php: library for drawing this specific graph

Tags: php, graph

I would like to ask you if you know any concrete library that is capable of drawing graph like:

[image]

so this is variation of something I would call "doube bipartitiate graph". Vertical lines just illustrate columns and i do not mean to draw a graph that look like sequence graph - just all nodes should lay somewhere on them. This picture illustrates what I mean:

[image]

The only thing we have found so far is [js.graph](http://js-graph-it.sourceforge.net/index.html) but it seems like it is a lot of work to make it look like it. Also, google charts does not seem appropriate. Any ideas?

Comment: lines [imageline()] and dots[imagefilledellipse()] are easy with the built in image functions as long as you an address start and end points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this [graph](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-ajax) may be useful

Thanks